# React JSS hover function value

Tags: css, reactjs, function, styled-components, jss

I'm trying to use a function value for the hover styling in a react component with JSS (I'm using the styled-jss library). I only want the hover styles applied when the 'edited' prop is true. Currently for the hover part I have this:

```
'&:hover': {
    background: props => props.edited && 'purple',
    cursor: props => props.edited && 'pointer',
    ...
}
```

This works fine, but as you can see I have to do the function value check for every hover CSS value. I want to just do the check once at the start and return the object if it's true:

```
'&:hover': props => props.edited && {
    background: 'purple',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    ...
}
```

But this syntax or something along those lines doesn't seem to be supported and I can't find any examples of this anywhere. Is there a simple way to do this? Or will I just have to do the function value check for every property in the hover object?

**EDIT:**

Here's a basic, generic example of my styled components and their JSS and how I'm using them:

```
/* style.js */
import styled from 'styled-jss';
const div = styled('div');

export const Style = {
    UpdateButton: div({
        color: props => !props.edited && 'grey',
        width: '200px',
        '&:hover': {
            background: props => props.edited && 'purple',
            cursor: props => props.edited && 'pointer'
        }
    })
};
```

Then in my react component:

```
import { Style } from './style';

class Settings extends Component {
        render() {
            return(
                <Style.UpdateButton/>
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently nested function rules have a bug https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/682

Answer (score 3):

You can extract your function outside you component and then just destructure like-

```
const getHoverStyles = (edited) => edited ? { color: 'red' } : {};

const styles = {
'&:hover': {...getHoverStyles(props.edited)}
}
```

PS: A much better alternative would be to have a css-in-js library like `jss` or `styled-components` or `aphrodite`, and then use them to declaratively define either `className` or inline styles for your component.

Hope this helps !

**UPDATES** -

I always prefer my styles to not be aware of props or state of the component. Styles should only be concerned with theme, spacing, typography, etc. So I'd go about defining 2 classes and apply then conditionally

```
<Button className={props.someProp ? class1 : class2} />
```

An even better solution would be to create more declarative Button using props. This means you'd have different props on Button based on some condition -

```
  <Button primary={!prop.edited} />  or {!prop.edited && <PrimaryButton/>}
  <Button secondary={prop.edited} /> or {prop.edited && <SecondaryButton/>}
```

Comment: I'm actually using styled-JSS: https://github.com/cssinjs/styled-jss, which is styled components + JSS. I've added an edit to my post to show how I'm actually implementing it, as I'm not sure how to use your response in my component context.